# Getting Error with Pytube: signature = cipher.get_signature(js, stream['s']) KeyError: 's'

Tags: urllib2, pytube

I have been this error when running my Pytube script:

```
     signature = cipher.get_signature(js, stream['s'])
     KeyError: 's'
```

My code is like this:

```
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='
    train_List = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(my_list):
        if len(my_list[i]) > 6:
            urls = url + my_list[i]
            train_List.append(urls)
            yt=YouTube(train_List[i])
            t=yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
            t[0].download('/pathtofolder')
            i+=1
```

I also tried:

```
    t=yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4').all()
```

I altered the cipher.py and helper.py files per the recommendation here: https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/353#issuecomment-455116197

but it hasn't fixed the problem. After making the alterations, I got the error noted above.

Next, I ran "pip install pytube --upgrade" per some other recommendations. Still getting the KeyError after it downloads a few audio files.

I've also implemented this in mixins.py, per the github issues:

```
    if ('signature=' in url) or ('&sig=' in url) or ('&lsig=' in url):
```

but now it's hanging after 3 uploads.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue (for me, at least) by changing line 49 in mixins.py to this:

```
signature = cipher.get_signature(js, stream['url'])
```

instead of

```
signature = cipher.get_signature(js, stream['s'])
```

and then changing lines 55-63 to

```
logger.debug(
    'finished descrambling signature for itag=%s\n%s',
    stream['itag'], pprint.pformat(
        {
            'url': stream['url'],
            'signature': signature,
        }, indent=2,
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. If I try a second time it works most of the time...

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQrkvZeE3Uc'
yt = YouTube(url)
yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, subtype='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().last().download()
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix the cipher.py file in lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytube:

In cipher.py, change pattern starting at line 38 to this:

```
pattern = [
    r'(["\'])signature\1\s*,\s*(?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\(',
    r'\.sig\|\|(?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\(',
    r'yt\.akamaized\.net/\)\s*\|\|\s*.*?\s*c\s*&&\s*d\.set\([^,]+\s*,\s*(?:encodeURIComponent\s*\()?(?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\(',
    r'\bc\s*&&\s*d\.set\([^,]+\s*,\s*(?:encodeURIComponent\s*\()?\s*(?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\(',
    r'\bc\s*&&\s*d\.set\([^,]+\s*,\s*\([^)]*\)\s*\(\s*(?P<sig>[a-zA-Z0-9$]+)\(',
]
```

Comment: thanks.This seems to be helping, however after downloading about 6 this way I got a VideoUnavailable error, and currently am trying to implement some error handling. After that works I'll be able to know if this regex change will fix it.

Comment: Well, what I did I create a while loop till the video is downloaded... That worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to solve it: `pip install git+https://github.com/nficano/pytube.git`

Other than that, check this [thread](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/333)

Answer (score 0):

I did `pip uninstall pytube`.

Checked my python version with `python --version`, turned out to be the Anaconda 3.6.8 version.

So I did `pip3 install pytube`, `pip3` being for Python 3 I believe.

It works no problems now.

Answer (score 0):

had same issue, based on other answers that installed it from sources, just checked my current pytube version, which was 9.5.0 and see that the last released is 9.5.2, so  I just run `pip install --upgrade pytube` and worked perfectly